# Bootstrap first LEGEND inside fieldset - no existent spacing in some browsers

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and getting great consistency across all browsers and devices, except for this issue. I've just tested our customer details form on an iPad1 in both Safari AND Chrome, and get the same issue I can't replicate else where. Where has the spacing gone between the legend and the first form group?

[image]

[image]

I have 2 other legends further down the form and the div/inputs immediately after have a nice margin as expected.

To prove it is always the first LEGEND causing the problem, I simply duplicated the legend tag (second screen shot) and hey presto, the spacing between the second legend and form-group is spot on.

I cannot explain this!

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="customer-form" action="#" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>To Purchase, Please Enter Your Personal Customer Details</legend>             


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="customer_title" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Title *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select name="customer_title" id="customer_title" class="form-control">
                          <option></option>
                          <option value="Mr">Mr. </option>
                          <option value="Mrs">Mrs. </option>
                          <option value="Miss">Miss. </option>
                          <option value="Ms">Ms. </option>
                          <option value="Dr">Dr. </option>
                          <option value="Rev">Rev. </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I'm using "bootstrap" - could you give more details about it? Maybe you are refering to twitter's bootstrap or another third party framework?

Comment: bootstrap.min.css -  * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: I can't replicate the error, chrome emulation for ipad1 doesn't present that problem, tested from here: http://www.bootply.com/3IeKaClw6x

Comment: Check this out: http://s30.postimg.org/7qvqc5fe9/IMG_20140529_110218.jpg - appreciate you looking at this for me!

Comment: have you added: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> to your head? also try it without the fieldset, use a div for example just to test

Comment: Yep I'm using that meta tag. I just changed that <legend> to <div> and the weirdest thing happened. The second <legend> on the form then went to the top where my first <legend> was. Even though in the markup it's half way down the form. Some javascript must be playing with the form (bootstrap?)

Comment: Well it is bootstrap's javascript on action, try replaceing all the legends, we might notice whose fault is your problem

Comment: Well I changed all to divs and the spacing disappeared, but I guess that was to be expected. Can I send you a URL to show you where this problem lies? I'd rather do that in private than display the URL here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54712/discussion-between-aboca-and-james-wilson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

```
.hack legend {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

.hack legend:after {
    display: block;
    height: 20px; /* @baseLineHeight; */
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    content: "";
  }
```

Another possible work-around, didn't work in this case:

```
form.form-horizontal > fieldset {
  & > legend {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  & > div.form-group:first-of-type > * {
    margin-top : 20px;
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2544